# How to apply CSS style for Angular JS drop down

Tags: html, css, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I have an requirement to show the Dropdown using angular JS.

In this drop down some values are having some 250 characters so dropdown becomes very big in size and the whole page itself becomes very big in size so I want to control this using some CSS styles but i dont know to do it for angular Js select drop down.

```
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
      <select ng-model="newrelatedFault" ng-options="item.FaultIdAndName for item in relatedFaults track by item.Id | filter: Fault.relatedFaults.isSelected(item)">
       <option value="">@selectLabel</option>
       </select>
     </td> <td>
     <a ng-click="Fault.relatedFaults.add(newrelatedFault.Id, newrelatedFaultDescription); newrelatedFault = null; newrelatedFaultDescription = null;" ng-disabled="newrelatedFault == null" class="btn btn-link btn-action"><i class="icon-plus" title="Add New"></i>Add</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: css does not change with angular.. its the same way to apply css without angular

Comment: Is there some way you can abbreviate the entries?

Comment: you can use some custom dropdowns like https://github.com/jseppi/angular-dropdowns and trim the characters using css ellipsis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a truncation with an ellipsis, as described in this [article by Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/).

> All the following are required, so the text must be in a single straight line that overflows a box where that overflow is hidden.

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

> [A bunch more techniques here, including multi-line ellipsis](http://html5hub.com/ellipse-my-text/).